# SSL problems running azure-webapp-maven-plugin config

Tags: azure-java-tools

when running:

```
mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.14.0:config
```

I end up with

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.14.0:config (default-cli) on project storingen-api: Max retries 0 times exceeded. Error Details: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.14.0:config (default-cli) on project storingen-api: Max retries 0 times exceeded. Error Details: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Clearly this is a certificate problem that cannot be found.  I have however no clue what certificate is needed nor in which keystore it needs to be.  I suppose in the cacerts of my java distribution but it's not clear in any way.

Does anyone know which cert and where to put it ?

Answer (score 0):

I just running into the same problem following [Azure Learn Java Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/intro-to-java-azure/6-sample-deployment)

Basically, this error ocurred because Java is trying to connect with your Azure Subscription at Azure Console. I saw the origin of this problem executing Maven command with -X. The log trace can be visualized [over here](https://pastebin.com/FShvu0kK), like this:

```
mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.12.0:config -X
```

What I did to solve:

1. I tried inserting Azure certifications inside Java cacerts - following the [explanation here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/pkix-path-building-failed-unable-to-find-valid-certification/ba-p/2591304). But it didn't change or solved the problem.
2. I searched for a new one version of azure-webapp-maven-plugin. Nowadays, the version is 2.3.0. You can check at [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-webapp-maven-plugin) the last version. **It fixed my problem and no more throws the error caused by Java.**

**before:** mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.12.0:config

**after (I think so, that version fixes the problem):** mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:2.3.0:config

Thanks